# Unable to locate link using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, href

Could you please help me to locate a link `Taschen` in the below piece of code?

**Code:**

```
<a data-flyout-target="handbags" title="Taschen" href="#">Taschen</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways by which you can identify this link:-

1. By.Xpath
2. By.LinkText

**Xpath:-**

```
//a[text()='Taschen']
//a[@data-flyout-target = 'handbags']
//a[@title='Taschen']
```

So you can identify it using `driver` object like:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("Put any of the above xpaths"));
```

Or Using LinkText

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Taschen"));
```

Hope it helps!